# If there is a double sharp on a note, does that mean the piece has modulated?

Tags: composition, accidentals, modulation

I'm currently writing a 32-bar free composition for my music exam coming up soon (I'm allowed to get help and advice on it, so this isn't cheating lol).
It's in F# major and I'd like to modulate to D# minor at some point. But right now, I wrote something like this (I use Noteflight plugged in to a midi keyboard) and this happened:

[image: two lines of piano music in F-sharp major, with some F-double-sharps on the second line]

Me and a friend were discussing our compositions earlier, and when I said I wanted to modulate to D# minor she said I'd have to use a C with a double sharp, aka a D. I've never encountered these symbols before today, so although I know it just sharpens the note twice, does the double sharp in the picture mean I've already modulated without intending to? Any advice on how to continue now? — I'm not sure what to do at the moment since it sounds nice, but I don't know what it's actually done.

Comment: If you transpose the piece down to D minor, that note becomes an F sharp.  Does the presence of the F sharp mean that you've modulated?

Comment: Not really the point of your question, but the large amount of dotted rhythms looks to me like there might be a simpler choice for time signature.  Wouldn't this be easier to read in 4/4?

Comment: In your question you mention a C double sharp, but your example only contains an A double sharp. Can you explain?

Comment: @JohnWu, I mentioned a C double sharp because that was the first time I heard about a double sharp- when my friend told me to use it when I modulated. So I was basically just providing the reason that I had the question- the way she phrased it made it seem like the double sharp should be used to show when you modulate, so when one showed up without me trying to modulate I was confused. Also, my example hasn't got an A double sharp, but an F double sharp. Sorry for the confusion :)

Comment: @JohnWu you've probably figured this out, but for the benefit of other readers who see an A double sharp in the image (as I also did), I would note that the top ledger line in the right hand in the second half of measure 14 is difficult to see unless you zoom in because it blends in with the note head.  This makes the F double sharp look at first glance like an A double sharp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Does the double sharp in the picture mean I've already modulated without intending to?

No, as is well explained by other posts.

#### Any advice on how to continue now?

The excerpt you've posted is primarily "in" E# minor. Since the two main chords are E# minor, that gives the passage its overall sound.<sup>1</sup>

The arrival of the D# major chord doesn't by itself constitute a modulation, because for the listener, their ears are still attuned to E# minor. However, if you continue the passage in D# major to better establish that sound in the listener's ear, then getting to D# minor will become easier.

In fact, as a short-cut, you could just immediately follow the D# major chord with a D# minor chord, and then continue in D# minor.

---

<sup>1.</sup> I put "in" in quotes, because, as you'll learn as your music theory education proceeds, you don't really follow the expectations of E# minor. However, the "overall sound" of the passage is important, and it clearly, to my ear, revolves around E# minor.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the piece is d# minor as my teacher explained to me today. I probably should've included a longer extract, so that's my fault, but it does mean that continuing in d# minor as you suggested wouldn't be modulation. I think shifting to the parallel major is modulating, so I'll probably just carry on in D# major. Thank you :)

Comment: @mza the traditional approach in classical music has been to use enharmonic equivalent keys to reduce the number of signs in the signature. Signatures with even seven signs are exceedingly rare; keys with double sharps or flats such as D♯ major are seen as a ridiculous thing to ask a performer to do. You should therefore consider writing the D♯ major section in E♭ major.  Since F♯ major and G♭ major both have six signs in the signature, you can choose either, but E flat minor will be more common than D♯ minor because the former will use natural accidentals where the latter uses double sharps.

Answer (score 12):

Let's restate your question generally as: *"does an accidental mean the piece has modulated?"*

An *accidental* in a passage does not necessarily mean the music has modulated. Sometimes chromatic tones are merely embellishment...

[image]

...like that `F#` which just embellishes a broken `C` chord. You wouldn't necessarily look at that accidental as indicating a modulation to `G` major. You can just call it a chromatic neighbor or auxiliary tone.

A secondary issue in your question is *enharmonic equivalents*. Your example `Cx` is enharmonically equivalent to `D`. Make sure you use key signatures and accidentals (including double sharps and double flats) to "spell" chords correctly. Your friend is right to say `Cx` is the pitch to use to modulate to `D#` major.

Comment: Auxilliary to *"Let's restate your question generally as: 'does an accidental mean the piece has modulated?'"*, this generalization works because double-sharps are just regular sharpened notes that were already sharp to begin with. That's why phoog's comment under the question mentions transposing everything to D minor (take one sharp from every note) - looking at it this way, the function of the formerly-doubled accidental is a lot easier to see. +1

Answer (score 6):

Sorry if this sounds harsh, but if you're required to deliver a page of notation for this exam, I strongly suggest you consult your teacher and check that this sort of Noteflight transcription is acceptable.

I don't think you've WRITTEN anything.  You've played something into Noteflight, which has done a remarkably good job of spelling the pitches (in a pretty extreme key!) but made a complete mess of notating the rhythms.  If you want to understand harmony, I suggest you use pencil and paper, or at least enter notes manually into a scoring program.

You've arrived at a chord of D♯ major.  The double sharp, in itself, doesn't mean there's been a modulation, any more than the earlier  B♯ accidentals do.  They just indicate that you've used a note that doesn't fit the key signature.  If it's 'just visiting' it doesn't count as a modulation.  If it becomes established, it might.

Comment: That's ok, I am allowed to use Noteflight and other softwares to compose. I don't actually have to submit anything written at all, and I did pick up on the inconsistent bar divisions so I'll probably just submit as an audio file.
I did ask my out-of-class piano teacher for some advice and she told me that the D# major chord counts as a tiers de picardie since (although in the part screenshotted it may not be clear) the piece is in d# minor, my mistake for saying f# major. 
Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: @mza That's ok then!   If you ARE at all interested in the notation, you might find it easier to spell this piece in Eb minor.  It's nice playing on 'all the black notes' isn't it!  A lot less chance of hitting a wrong one.

Answer (score 2):

In key D♯ minor, the leading note will be a C note of some kind. It will have to be one semitone below the root/tonic of D♯, and C♯ is a whole tone below. Therefore, that leading note will need to be Cx - C double sharp. What may be easier is to write in key F, and modulate to key Dm. That would put the leading note as C♯. Reasoning being writing music down is in order to make it accessible for others to play. An awful lot of folk will look at D♯ minor, and dismiss it. Such a shame!

Answer (score 2):

In this case you have elected to write a D# major triad. D#-Fx-A# is the proper way to spell a D# major triad in any key. The spelling of a triad must use every other letter thus, F## or Fx instead of G. The double sharps are simply accidentals, not a modulation, In this case they create a parallel major chord. If you were to continue to write in the parallel major key (better spelled as Eb) then it would be a modulation.

You are actually a bit lucky, sometimes notation programs don’t spell non-diatonic chords enharmonically correctly.